# MacMini 2021 M1 - Force Purge HD space

Tags: hard-drive, mac-mini, purge

Does anyone know a way to free up the purgeable space on a MacMini M1 HD?

AppleCare said it'll purge itself in time, but it's been 2 weeks and I need that space because the HD is so small

256GB HD with 78GB purgeable is like 30% unavailable

I tried to copy a block of files over thinking the system would automatically reclaim the space, but it remains unavailable.

[image: MacMini-M1-GetInfo-Purge]

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254676/how-do-i-clear-the-purgeable-area-on-my-disk

Answer (score 0):

@tetsujin's link above worked very well

I made a series of increasingly larger empty volumes via Disk Utility and the system reclaimed the space